# How do you analyse the structure of the phrase "by then"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/then), **then** is an adverb or adjective, not a noun. If it can't be a noun, how can it follow a preposition in this sentence?

> They will be gone **by then**.

Comment: Are you not similarly puzzled by *before now, after tonight, by tomorrow, every now and then, every so often*? :)

Comment: @tchrist now, tonight and tomorrow  are listed as nouns in the Cambridge Dictionary. "every so often" is certainly a strange one.

Comment: You just need to get a better dictionary, I'm afraid. At least, if you plan to take it as some sort of inerrant holy writ you do. :) The OED covers this particular circumstance and several other related ones as well. Reasoning will lead you to the correct answer, no matter what a dictionary may say.

Comment: Preliminary point: prepositions don't take only nouns as complement but also preposition phrases, adverb phrases, and even clauses. Modern grammar treats "then" as a preposition, so in your example "by then" is a preposition phrase with "then" used anaphorically and functioning as complement of the prep "by".